# Apalike Bibliographystyle

Tags: bibtex, apa-style

I am currently working no my Masterthesis. I import it the packages...:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{apalike}
```

And then add the references section in this way:

```
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{bib}
```

The resulting bibliography is:

XXX, D. M., XXX, A., and XXX, P. (2012). title of article. international journal XY, 49:479–487.

XXX, A. and XXX, D. (2004). Title of inproceeding. In Booktitle, pages 327–330. IEEE.

....In Bibtex, the first entry is an "article", the second an "inproceeding". It seems strange to me that in the second one the word "pages" is written, in the first entry not. From my point of view this seems to be inconsistent.

Do I anything wrong? Is it possible to fix this "issue" somehow?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 6):

As the name might imply, the `apalike` style does not attempt to conform rigidly to the guidelines set out in [APA style guide](http://www.apastyle.org/). The formatting of an inproceedings reference by `apalike` deviates from the strict APA style. That said, in strict APA style `pp` is used to denote the pages in books and proceedings (as opposed to `pages` in `apalike`), but not in journal articles. You can always edit the `bst` file to change a style if you do not like it.