# Apalike package not available?

Tags: packages, miktex, apa-style

I wanted to install the apalike package, but got an error that "The remote package repository is not online". I tried to change the repository from my default address "http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/" to another one, but I cannot find the apalike package there. And it isn't [here](http://ctan.org/pkg/apalike) either. Has it been removed? Is apalike2 the same thing (i.e. interchangable with apalike, shall I install it instead?)?

Comment: There never was a package called `apalike`.  Are you perhaps looking for [`apacite`](https://ctan.org/pkg/apacite)?

Comment: No, it was called apalike, I am sure of that (it even was in the package repository that became unavailable). Now there is apalike2, that's why I am asking if it is the updated version of the aforementioned.

Comment: There is `apalike.bst` which is a standard style of BibTeX, but there is no and never was a package called `apalike`.  To use the BibTeX style use `\bibliographystyle{apalike}`.  I highly doubt that it was superseded by `apalike2` as this is from 1998.

Comment: Then why did I see it in my MikTeX Package Manager and was required to install it? In this case, where can I find the `apalike.bst` to be able to use the apalike bibliography style? (When using the `\bibliographystyle{apalike}` command, I received an error claiming that there is no such package.

Comment: This question addressed this bibliography style, but not where to get it: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155361/apalike-bibliographystyle

Answer (score 1):

I found the source! It can be downloaded, together with some other older files, from [CTAN Archive](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/base?lang=en)